# Exim4 MySQL error

Tags: ubuntu, email, exim

Arg, spend the whole day fixing Exim4, and now I get this strange error:

```
2011-04-23 20:31:12 failed to expand "${lookup mysql{SELECT DISTINCT transport FROM mail_transports WHERE transport = '${quote_mysql:$domain}'}}" while checking a list: lookup of "SELECT DISTINCT transport FROM mail_transports WHERE transport = '***.net'" gave DEFER: incomplete MySQL server data: 127.0.0.1
2011-04-23 20:31:12 H=(195031.***.nl) [212.61.252.31] F=<kevin@***.nl> temporarily rejected RCPT <kevin@***.net>: incomplete MySQL server data: 127.0.0.1
```

In 01_exim4-config_listmacrosdefs I use this:

```
MYSQL_SERVER=127.0.0.1:3307
MYSQL_USER=***
MYSQL_PASSWORD=***
MYSQL_DB=***
hide mysql_servers = 127.0.0.1:3307/<db>/<user>/<pass>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colon is normally used as a list separator in the exim4 config. You will need to escape it in the host/port specification:

127.0.0.1::3307

See: http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch09.html#SECID73

Comment: That did the trick indeed :).

Answer (score 0):

Normally in situations like this, you can use "localhost" instead of the IP/Port combination. This is one possible reason. The other might be, that there are spaces between the = sign in the last line of your code.

Comment: I created 2 SQL servers and I want to use the one that uses port 3307. I tried to remove the spaces, but still got that error...

Comment: Yes, i missed that. I did a quick search and found out: The MySQL option is eventually not enabled in your exim distribution. Debian/Ubuntu sihps a light and a heavy version of exim4, but I actually don't know all the activated features. I use DBmail to work with mails and MySQL. But this approach is also interesting for smaller mailserver.

Comment: BTW: There is normally an option to connect to local mysql servers without the tcp/ip stack in between. It's faster and uses less resources. Normally you can point to the socket file in /var/mysql/ or wherever your MySQL resides.